# cancel a web request and handle errors inside the ReverseProxy Director function

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, go-http

I am wondering if it would be possible to cancel a web request or send an internal response to the client inside the `ReverseProxy.Director` function.

Suppose we do something that throws an error, or we have other reason to not forward the request.

```golang
proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
    Director: func(r *http.Request) {
        err := somethingThatThrows()
    },
}

http.Handle("/", proxy)
```

A solution to this might be the below, but it's not as neat as the above way to use the proxy. I am also not sure to which degree the request should be modified that way. The director seems to be the place to do that.

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := somethingThatThrows()
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    proxy.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if it would be possible to cancel a web request [...]

You can cancel the request that is passed to the `Director` function, **BUT** there are some details to consider:

- the correct way to cancel a request is to cancel its context
- you can not cancel contexts where you didn't set a (deadline|timeout|cancelfunc) yourself → i.e. you must have access to the `cancel` function → i.e. you can't cancel *parent* contexts created by someone else.
- the `*http.Request` passed to `Director` function is a clone of the original request

Based on the points above, you can replace the request in the `Director` with another one that has a cancellable context. It may look like the following:

```
proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
    Director: func(req *http.Request) {

        // create a cancellable context, and re-set the request
        ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(req.Context())
        *req = *req.WithContext(ctx)

        err := somethingThatThrows()
        if err != nil {
            cancel()
            return
        }
    },
}
```

Then the code above doesn't do anything else by itself. What should happen is that the `httputil.ReverseProxy.Transport` function, which implements `http.RoundTripper` checks whether the request context is cancelled, before actually send anything to the upstream service.

The documentation of `Director` states:

> Director must be a function which modifies the request into a new request to be sent using Transport.

When the `Transport` is not provided, it will fall back to `http.DefaultTransport`, which aborts the request when the context is cancelled. The current code (Go 1.17.5) looks like:

```
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            req.closeBody()
            return nil, ctx.Err()
        default:
        }
```

If you provide your own implementation of `http.RoundTripper` you may want to implement that behavior yourself. Remember also that the context done channel is `nil` if it's not cancellable, so you *have to* set a cancel func **and call `cancel()`** in order to have that `select` run the "done" case.

---

> or send an internal response to the client inside the ReverseProxy.Director

Based on the same quote above docs, you should **not** write to the `http.ResponseWriter` from within the `Director` function — assuming you are even closing around it. As you can see the `Director` itself doesn't get the `http.ResponseWriter` as an argument, and this should already be a self-explanatory detail.

If you want to specify some other behavior in case the request can't be forwarded, and assuming that whatever implementation of `http.RoundTripper` is returning `error` when the req context is cancelled, you can provide your `ReverseProxy.ErrorHandler` function:

```
proxy.ErrorHandler = func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, err error) {
    // inspect err
    // write to writer
}
```

The `ErrorHandler` will be invoked when `Transport` returns error, including when the error comes from a cancelled request, and it does have `http.ResponseWriter` as an argument.

Comment: I just noticed this doesnt seem to work. I cancelled the context and the proxy still made the request to upstream. At least it appeared like it. I got 2 timeout errors in the code and the client didnt receive a response upon cancelling the context but only on the second timeout.

Comment: @TheFool yes there's a silly bug in the code, the line `req = req.WithContext(ctx)` is overwriting the pointer, not the request data. Should change to `*req = *req.WithContext(ctx)` https://go.dev/play/p/jYz_fA1nn2h

Comment: however TBH the entire thing feels like a hack, you should probably run the code-that-can-error outside the director. If the director were meant to handle errors it'd have a different signature

Comment: I agree, I have switched to the idea with wrapping the proxy's ServeHTTP in a handler and doing the work there, upfront. Then I can return an error code even before calling the proxy, if needed.  It is also no problem modifying the request in this handler, it seems.